# dynamically adding DOM element click event function not working in angularJs application

Tags: angularjs, event-handling

I'm trying to add new DOM element dynamically which has click event handler - already defined function. Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="miniapp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div id="div" ng-click="addingEvent()">DIV </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $scope;
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
   $scope.addingEvent = function(){
      var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#div' ) );
      myEl.append('<a ng-click="afterEvent()" href="#">anchor addedd </br> </a>'); 
   };

   $scope.afterEvent = function(){
      alert('after event');
   };

};
```

[Here's the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hmoju8ps/3/). As you see, while the anchor is added, the click event is not handled correctly. How to fix it?

Comment: Are you using angular directives such as `ng-if` to manipulate the DOM? You should avoid manipulating it directly whenever possible.

Comment: No , trying to using controller function only

Comment: in js fiddle you can check its simple and straight forward requiremnet

Comment: solved https://jsfiddle.net/hmoju8ps/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not enough to just append an element into DOM: you'll have to let Angular know about it. One possible approach (listing only the controller here for brevity):

```
function Ctrl($scope, $compile) {
   var anchorTemplate = '<a ng-click="afterEvent()" href="#">anchor addedd </br> </a>';

   $scope.addingEvent = function(){
     var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#div' ) );
     var $anchor = angular.element(anchorTemplate);
     $compile($anchor)($scope);
     myEl.after($anchor);
   };
}
```

Here's [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b11zu581/) to play with, with some good practices applied as well. Yet, as a matter of fact, I'd rather have this functionality implemented as a directive (component in terms of Angular 1.5).

Answer (score 1):

So, I have modified your code using ng-if statement. There is no need to remove or add elements in DOM using old JS ways.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="miniapp" ng-controller="Ctrl">

<div id="div" ng-click="addingEvent()">DIV <span><a ng-click="afterEvent()" href="#" ng-if="showAnchor">anchor addedd </a></span></div>


</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
var $scope;
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {

            $scope.showAnchor=false;
      $scope.addingEvent = function(){

            $scope.showAnchor=true;

    };
     $scope.afterEvent = function(){
       alert('after event');
    };

};
```

Comment: Thanks Nitesh for giving time, i have given that example to demonstration purpose only , basically i have requirement to add anchor link dynamically on the base of API response .

Answer (score 1):

Solved [Jsfiddle demo updated](https://jsfiddle.net/hmoju8ps/5/)

```
    myEl.append($compile('<a ng-click="afterEvent()" href="#">anchor addedd </br> </a>')($scope));
```

This will work